# How to use Picker value from a View in Android class

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, picker

I am creating an app (C# Xamarin Forms + Firebase) in which user is picking some data from the picker, an based on that I should perform a query on my Firebase database. The problem is that I do not know, how to take the data picked by the user and use it to build a query which is in another class.
( android/iOS, not in a shared code project). As it is small amount of data, now one of my pickers looks f.e. like this:

```
 <Picker x:Name="TastePicker" Title="Jaki smak lubisz najbardziej?">
                <Picker.ItemsSource>
                    <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                        <x:String>Słodki</x:String>
                        <x:String>Słony</x:String>
                        <x:String>Gorzki</x:String>
                        <x:String>Kwaśny</x:String>
                    </x:Array>
                </Picker.ItemsSource>
            </Picker>
```

Do You have any idea on how can I solve this?
Thank You.

Comment: generally, you would expose your Android code via DependencyService to Forms and interact with it that way

Comment: Further reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction

Comment: Sometimes, a single comment can help a lot. That was the case. 
Thanks guys, all is working now!

Answer (score 0):

[Dependency Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/) class is a service locator that enables Xamarin.Forms applications to invoke native platform functionality from shared code.

In shared Project:

```
public interface IQueryService
{
    void queryData(string value);
}
```

In Android/iOS:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(QueryService))]
namespace App365.Droid/App365.iOS
{
    public class QueryService : IQueryService
    {
        public void queryData(string value)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Call it in shared project:

```
 DependencyService.Get<IQueryService>().queryData(value);
```